# How To Create Ajax-Based Pages for Recently Uploaded Products in Woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I created a page in Woocommerce to show the latest uploaded products.
To do this, I first created a template called Recent Product in the child theme.

Then, I created an AJAX responder function in function.php (in the child theme) to load the products with Ajax when you scroll the page.

Finally, I defined this page from wp-admin>pages>add new page>(template: Recent Product) section.

I am encountering 2 problems and although I tried hard, I could not solve the problems. I could not find a similar study.

1-) Ajax works strangely sometimes; sometimes it doesn't work. When it works, it only works once. Only page 3 is loaded.
There are no errors in the console. I activated debug.log. There is no error there either.

2-) The other problem is that some product columns appear empty. For example, there are always 4 products in the first row. However, the first product in line 2 is not loading. This place comes up empty. So the fifth product section is empty. I examine this in the Inspect section of the 2nd row, 1st column. A li element has not been created for this place.

I would be glad if someone could help me solve these problems. I've been struggling with this for hours but couldn't find a solution.

My code working is below:

**Template File**

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ){exit; /*Exit if accessed directly*/ }
/*
 * Template Name: Recent Product
 * 
 * @author: X
 */
get_header();
?>
<div id="product-container" class="custom-recent-products">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'product',
        'posts_per_page'    => 12,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC', // Use 'DESC' to show recently uploaded products first
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_stock_status',
                'value'   => 'instock', 
                'compare' => '=', 
            ),
        ),
        'post_status'       => 'publish', 
    );
    
    $products_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    if ($products_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($products_query->have_posts()) {
            $products_query->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part('content', 'product'); // View WooCommerce product content
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var page = 2; // first page number
        var loading = false; 

        function loadMoreProducts() {
            if (loading) return;
            loading = true;

            $.post(
                '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                {
                    action: 'wc_recent_products',
                    nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('wc_recent_products'); ?>',
                    page: page, // Sayfa numarasını POST verisi olarak gönderin
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        $('#product-container').append(response); // Add uploaded products into #product-container
                        page++; // Increase next page number
                        loading = false;
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        // Load more products as you get closer to the bottom of the page
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 200) {
                loadMoreProducts();
            }
        });

        // first loading
        loadMoreProducts();
    });
</script>
```

**function.php**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wc_recent_products', function () {
    if (isset($_POST['nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'wc_recent_products')) {
        $page       = isset($_POST['page']) ? absint($_POST['page']) : 1;
        $per_page   = 12; // Number of products to display on each page
        $offset     = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

        $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'posts_per_page'    => $per_page,
            'offset'            => $offset,
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
        );

        $products_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($products_query->have_posts()) {
            ob_start();

            while ($products_query->have_posts()) {
                $products_query->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part('content', 'product'); // WooCommerce ürün içeriğini görüntüle
            }

            wp_reset_postdata();

            echo ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
    exit();
});
```